# Why is filter not picking up "not 0.0"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter, identity

I've defined the function

```
def f(array):
    return list(filter(lambda x: (x is not 0.0) and (x is not 0), array))
```

and here's what happens we I try to pass a list with a 0.0 in it.

```
>>> f([0.0, 1, 0, 2, False])
[0.0, 1, 2, False]
```

What I'd expect returned is `[1, 2, False]` since my filter should have thrown out the 0.0 and 0, but not the False.

For some reason, the filter is not picking up the `x is not 0.0` part, but it's working on the `x is not 0` part fine.  I'm dumbfounded.

---

**Edit:** I've added in a False value to show why I'm not just using `x != 0`.